# While data loading using oracle apex i should lookup to other table for matching id and pull a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I'm building an application using Oracle Apex 4.2.
 t1 
----------------------- 
id country 
1  usa 
2  uae 
3  uk 

below screenshot has 'SUBJECT ID' which i should compare against table 't2' and pull 'PRIMARY OWNER QID' details while uploading.
[image]

```
t2
------------------------
id country
1   -
2   -
3  uk
4  UNk
```

based on t1 tables 'SUBJECT_ID' application should load 'PRIMARY OWNER QID' details on the report/form onload.
[image]

I have already created a form which captures table 't1' details but need to create an import wizard to pick a .csv file which contains table 't2' details.

I have imported .csv file to application using oracle's default feature 'DATA LOADING' but i want to join table 't2' with table 't1' so that it will output the following table

```
t3
-------------------
id country
1  USA
2  UAE
3  UK
```

Thanks for your help friends.

unable to figure out in the 'DATA LOADING' option.I request to guide me easy steps to do this onload/while upload of the page.

Comment: Is the country UK from t1 different form UNK in t2? or is it a mistype?

Comment: hi cristian, yes UK from t2 different from UNK in t2 with different id's

Comment: What is the logic behind getting t3? Why don't you have in t3 the record with id 3 from t1?

Comment: apologies for typo error cristian, need to get the 'COUNTRY' value to table 't3' while uploading csv file ( 't2' data) matching the 'ID' of table t2 it should output 't3' values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest modifying the Wizard Page which Displays the "Data Validation" process for an Import Wizard. Then your users can use the dialog on their own.

For the SQL Query, you can do a simple Query for you T3 Data:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (SELECT NVL(T2.ID, T1.ID) AS ID, NVL(T2.COUNTRY, T1.COUNTRY) AS COUNTRY FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.ID= T2.ID)
```

You can include this in the process or use it for a one time conversion.

Comment: Thanks @rarspace01 .. i have tried above code in the process section but unfortunately it is throwing error couldn't process it.

Comment: could you give us the error? then we can fix it/i can correct the sql

Comment: Thanks for asking @rarspace01 i can see the below error in process window.
"1 error has occurred
ORA-06550: line 2, column 13: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored".

Comment: It looks like you have a different t3 structure than described. Could you add your DML (sql create) Skript to the question  for us to have the structure of you tables. This would help us to write a fitting sql query for you

Comment: thanks for the reply  i have used your query but bit modified it ,now i can fetch values dynamically and update my table 't3' (i.e., 'apt_mdr_allocation' in the app) `update apt_mdr_allocation set primary_owner_qid = (SELECT primary_owner_qid FROM apt_mdr_subject_owner where subject_id = apt_mdr_allocation.subject_id),secondary_owner_qid = (select secondary_owner_qid from apt_mdr_subject_owner where subject_id = apt_mdr_allocation.subject_id),
tertiary_owner_qid = ( select tertiary_owner_qid from apt_mdr_subject_owner where subject_id = apt_mdr_allocation.subject_id);`

Comment: **but whenever i upload a csv file it is inserting new rows which is leading to duplications ,so can you guide me wherein for every upload if it checks for existing rows and updates it and if existing rows are not present in previous table it should inserts remaining rows. please let me know if i need to elaborate**

Comment: If you are using Oracle 10>= then you can use thte MERGE Command.

`MERGE INTO t3 a
  USING (YOUR SOURCE QUERY) b
    ON (a.ID = b.ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.primary_owner_qid = b.primary_owner_qid 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, primary_owner_qid )
    VALUES (b.id, b.primary_owner_qid );`

Comment: thnks ,i tried above code `merge into t3 a 
using t1 b on (a.subject_id=b.subject_id)
when matched then update set a.primary_owner_qid = b. primary_owner_qid
when not matched then insert (subject_id,primary_owner_qid) values ( b.subject_id,b.primary_owner_qid);`  but still i can see duplications . let me know if i'm putting it r8.

Comment: can you try:
`MERGE INTO t3 a USING (SELECT NVL(T2.ID, T1.ID) AS ID, NVL(T2.COUNTRY, T1.COUNTRY) AS COUNTRY FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.ID= T2.ID)) b ON (a.ID = b.ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.primary_owner_qid = b.primary_owner_qid WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, primary_owner_qid ) VALUES (b.id, b.primary_owner_qid );`
This is more or less the direction

Comment: i tried code wid my values `MERGE INTO apt_mdr_allocation a USING (SELECT NVL(apt_mdr_allocation.subject_id,apt_mdr_subject_owner.subject_id) AS subject_id, NVL(apt_mdr_allocation.primary_owner_qid,apt_mdr_subject_owner.primary_owner_qid) AS primary_owner_qid FROM apt_mdr_allocation LEFT JOIN apt_mdr_subject_owner ON a.subject_id= b.subject_id)) b ON (a.subject_id = b.subject_id) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.primary_owner_qid = b.primary_owner_qid WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (subject_id, primary_owner_qid ) VALUES (b.subject_id, b.primary_owner_qid );` bt i see ORA-00969: missing ON keyword

Comment: just to make the problem clear t1 = apt_mdr_subject_owner,t2=apt_mdr_allocation,t3=apt_mdr_allocation [ while data loading - i'm uploading data to t3, but we need to update the matching rows of t3 while we perform upload again it should insert new rows to t3 table when no matching rows are found. please let me know if i'm clear with what i'm asking rarspace01. Thanks for your support

Comment: thanks for your support buddy. Issue got resolved using oracle apex data loading feature itself. we need to prvodie unique columns while setting up data loading feature . So when ever unique columns matches its respective columns in the excel file it will update the target if it doesn't match then it will insert new rows. Hope this solution help others too...:)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I dont know if i understand it correctly but try this:

```
SELECT t2.id as ID, t1.country as COUNTRY FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id ORDER BY t2.id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have placed the above select statement in my insert statement but i can see error  saying "too many values".i need to place the sql code in the data validation page wherein it need to execute while i perform 'DATA UPLOADING' using oracle's default feature. thanks for ur answer @brenners1302